# Can you specify different font size for each fallback font?

Tags: silverlight, fonts

When specifying a fallback font in Silverlight, is it possible to pair it with a font size?

The problem is that different fonts take different amount of space at a given font size. I'd like to be able to provide font size for each fallback font to make them more compatible in terms of space consumption.

Comment: +1, good question. i'd be interested in the answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Silverlight 4, the answer is No.  This is a great idea, and you should push for it! (Go [here](http://connect.microsoft.com) to request it)

**fallbackFontFamilyName value only helps Silverlight FIND a font, not use it.**

Here are the docs for [FontFamily](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [FontSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.fontsource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

XAML allows you to specify PT, or PX as the measurement for every [FontSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979721%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).  However, Silverlight doesn't care, and defaults all font sizes to PX.  It would be nice if you could give a specific size for each USE of a font.

+1 for WPF, -1 to consistency